# C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations

Tags: c++

I am getting the error "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations" on my "const MAX = 10;" line.

Here is my code:

```
//A program that adds up the maximum of 10 numbers ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 )


#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
const MAX = 10; //the error is here!

int main()
{
int sum, num;
sum = 0;
num = 1;

do
{
    sum = sum + num;
    num++;
}

while (num <= MAX);
{
    cout << "Sum = ";
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `MAX`?

Comment: Try `const auto MAX = 10;`

Comment: @KaidulIslam, why not? It's a specific question about programming. And it features a MCVE. So it fits the format. It's not particularly interesting or well written, but that's what we get our votes for.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I've only started programming 2 weeks ago, sorry about the amateur questions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, C++ requires a type specifier for the declaration. For instance, change `const MAX = 10;` to `const int MAX = 10;`.

Answer (score -4):

Have you considered using

```
#define MAX 10
```

?

Comment: Worst advice ever.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ... uhmmm ... Why?

Comment: Macros have well known drawbacks and pitfalls, it's always better to have a clearly typed constant.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's the old "define vs const" song.

Comment: I should answer "use #define MAX ((int)10)", but it would be only for the show. Which is the best code? the one which actually suits all the requirements, which we can't guess from the question. just to clarify: #define is best in embedded world, with int (but not with strings, for instance) and const int is best in other situations. The right answer? "it depends". BR

Comment: this still doesn't answer the question